# DPD Auto and crosscorrelation

Tags: signal-processing

I am trying to learn signal processing and digital pre-distortion.

http://www.altera.com/end-markets/wireless/advanced-dsp/predistortion/wir-digital-predistortion.html

I am currently trying to auto correlate the input signal and from this I make a matrix.  I then get the coefficients for this matrix and use them with a LUT to help pre-distort the signal. I am having difficulty understanding what these coefficients represent?  Why are they useful when added to the LUT? So the coefficients are used as a weight in those LUTs. Can anyone give me a pointer?

Same goes for the cross-correlation with the feedback, what do the coefficients from that vector represent?

Answer (score 1):

The digital pre-distortion is used to make the output of the non-linear (power) amplifier almost linear again. Problem is, that the nonlinearity of the amplifier is not constant (depends on the signal) and the signal to be amplified has to be processed in advance. I guess the coefficients are used for that case.